# How to define multiple variables in one deep in a EmberJS path route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to define a path which looks like that: `diff/:left...:right`

The params in the route looks is `{left...:right: "1...2"}`.

Is there some special syntax to use when the variables are not between two slashes `/`?

Comment: Could you define it as a single variable, i.e. `diff/:range`, then check that it is in the `x...y` format?

Comment: Yes this is what I will end to do if there are nothing out of the box... Thanks